# Solr email address search returns 0 results

Tags: solr

I am trying to allow for partial or full email search in Solr  4.0.

Here are my test cases:

- flast@company.com
- flast

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101639/solr-partial-email-search-with-exact-match). But I am not getting the exact result for the first case where the whole email is provided and not getting any result for the second result (which happens to be a unique value), which means Solr isn't looking into the email field.

Here is the truncated schema. I must be missing something obvious, but I am not seeing it.

```
<schema name="Search" version="1.5">
<types>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="text_email" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</types>

<fields>
    .
    .
    .
    <field name="email" type="text_email" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    .
    .
    .
</fields>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wordDelimiterFilterFactory as below.

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="0"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"
                />
```

`generateWordParts="1"` will help to generate parts of words:

`preserveOriginal="1"` causes the original token to be indexed without modifications.

The final type should look like :

```
<analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="0"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="0"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
```